# Json starting with [ foreach warning

Tags: php, json, decode

I need to grab some json code; it is starting with `[`

If I try to loop it, I retrieve

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can someone help me to decode properly this json? thanks

PHP Code:

```
echo "<h2>Tradedoubler Coupon</h2>";
$tdjson = file_get_contents("http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/vouchers.json;voucherTypeId=1?token=280C407EC3D32D2C8E4C04A100DD00FEA9000580");
//$tdobj = json_decode(print_r($tdjson));
$tdobj = json_decode($tdjson,true);
//foreach($tdobj as $prog ) {
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . print_r($tdobj) . '</li>
</ul>';
```

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        id: 20108,
        programId: 17269,
        programName: "",
        code: "6G4KGGDH",
        updateDate: "1369813973159",
        publishStartDate: "1370037600000",
        publishEndDate: "1372629599999",
        startDate: "1370037600000",
        endDate: "1372629599999",
        title: "Sconto",
        shortDescription: "kkkkk",
        description: "kkkk",
        voucherTypeId: 1,
        defaultTrackUri: "http://url.com/click?a(1556954)p(17269)ttid(13)",
        siteSpecific: false,
        discountAmount: 5,
        isPercentage: false,
        publisherInformation: "",
        languageId: "it",
        exclusive: false,
        currencyId: "EUR",
        logoPath: "http://url.com/file/17269/eDreams_100x50.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 19699,
        programId: 29519,
            programName: "",
        code: "6G4KGGDH",
        updateDate: "1369813973159",
        publishStartDate: "1370037600000",
        publishEndDate: "1372629599999",
        startDate: "1370037600000",
        endDate: "1372629599999",
        title: "Sconto",
        shortDescription: "kkkkk",
        description: "kkkk",
        voucherTypeId: 1,
        defaultTrackUri: "http://url.com/click?a(1556954)p(17269)ttid(13)",
        siteSpecific: false,
        discountAmount: 5,
        isPercentage: false,
        publisherInformation: "",
        languageId: "it",
        exclusive: false,
        currencyId: "EUR",
        logoPath: "http://url.com/file/17269/eDreams_100x50.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: `var_dump($tdobj)`, what do you get?

Comment: you are decoding the JSON string, so the $json should look like a string not object. Wrap the content with quotes and make it as string.

Comment: var_dump($tdobj) = bool(true)

Comment: Try adding single quotes around the JSON. In the more recent releases of PHP, they've added support for the `[]` array notation, so in lack of quotes, your data might be parsed here

Comment: so i can't modify the json file, i get it from Tradedoubler

Comment: Post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON from Tradedoubler is invalid. The problem is it doesn't put double quotes around the object property names, only the values.

Take this for example:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "id": 20108,
        "programId": 17269,
        "programName": "",
        "code": "6G4KGGDH"
    },
    {
        "id": 19699,
        "programId": 29519,
        "programName": "",
        "code": "6G4KGGDH"
    }
]';

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

In the above JSON, I've added the double quotes that are necessary, and if you run that code, you'll see that it will successfully output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20108
            [programId] => 17269
            [programName] => 
            [code] => 6G4KGGDH
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 19699
            [programId] => 29519
            [programName] => 
            [code] => 6G4KGGDH
        )

)
```

Therefore you have two options:

1. Contact Tradedoubler and request for them to supply valid JSON
2. Parse the property names that are missing the quotes and insert them, which would correct the original invalid JSON.

---

If you want to test whether a snippet of JSON is valid or not, you can paste it into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) which will tell you where any errors are. If you paste your JSON from tradedoubler, it will indeed tell you that it's invalid.

Comment: @Pigi just be a good supporter and if his answer is useful do upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: finally I have solution: Tradedoubler provides also an xml version of the voucher file so using curl you can decode it:

Answer (score 0):

finally I have solution: Tradedoubler provides also an xml version of the voucher file so using curl you can decode it:

```
    <?php

$url="http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/vouchers?token=YOURTOKEN";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);

?>
```

and to loop results:

```
<?php

$url="http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/vouchers?token=YOUR TOKEN HERE";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach ($xml->voucher as $coupon){
echo '<li>'.$coupon->id.' - '.$coupon->programId.' - '.$coupon->programName.' - '.$coupon->code.' - '.$coupon->title.' - '.$coupon->shortDescription.' - '.$coupon->description.'</li>';
}

?>
```